# OSPF interfaces

Tags: cisco

Is it possible to use two ospf interfaces connected from Core switch to the Distribution switch each one has a different subset?
[image]

Comment: It is the interfaces, not the devices, that get put into OSPF areas. An entire link (the interfaces on both ends, is what is in the OSPF area.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, Yes.   However, if the devices are in different areas, then you have to put both subnets in one area or the other.

Comment: Yes, both are in the same area.

Comment: Then you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
Now, keep in mind that only one link will  be added to the forwarding table while the other will remain as backup... Unless you enable load-balance